# Modify namespace prefix Web Services C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

we are receiving a SOAP request and we can't modify it all. So now we have to change our webservice to fit in with the call. Im pretty much there, expect the prefix for their namespace is different to the one that gets generated and it doesn't hit the method unless its the same:

Here is my Webservice:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://domain.co.za/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class MyWebservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
{   
    [WebMethod]        
    public string PushMessage(object payload)
    {
    }
}
```

And the SOAP they are sending:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://domain.co.za/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns0:username soapenv:actor=""></ns0:username>
    <ns0:password soapenv:actor=""></ns0:password>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns0:PushMessage>
    <type>confirmation</type>
    <autoRelease>true</autoRelease>
        <payload>
            <Confirmation>
                <MessageEnvelope>
                .
                .
                </MessageEnvelope>
            </Confirmation>
        </payload>
    </ns0:PushMessage>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see they are using ns0, the one that gets generates by the WDSL is web, is there anyway to force my namespace to generate as ns0: instead of the default web:

And is there a way to remove the ns0/web from the payload element? They are not sending the namespace with the payload, but the WDSL generates it as web:payload

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Calendar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>" +
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns0=\"http://domain.co.za/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
              "<soapenv:Header>" +
                "<ns0:username soapenv:actor=\"\">            </ns0:username>" +
                "<ns0:password soapenv:actor=\"\">            </ns0:password>" +
              "</soapenv:Header>" +
              "<soapenv:Body>" +
                "<ns0:PushMessage>" +
                  "<type>confirmation            </type>" +
            "<autoRelease>true            </autoRelease>" +
                  "<payload>" +
                    "<Confirmation>" +
                      "<MessageEnvelope>" +
                      "</MessageEnvelope>" +
                    "</Confirmation>" +
                  "</payload>" +
                "</ns0:PushMessage>" +
              "</soapenv:Body>" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

            string pattern = "(</?)(\\w:)(\\w)";
            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern);
            input = expr.Replace(input, "$1$3");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: the problem is that I am not making the request and don't have any control over it, so I have to form my webservice method exactly to the above message.

Comment: You asked to remove the ns and that is what I did.  So you can modify the receive message any way you choose before processing the message.